# Getting many models in one Rails API endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I'm sifting through a few Rails 5 API tutorials and all the endpoints are as you would expect: `/todos` for getting all todos, `/todos/:id/items` for getting a todo item, etc.

I'm building an API where a Site has Tutorials and TutorialItems. I am first wondering if with a Rails API it is possible to create a custom endpoint like `/init_tutorials` that would get a site's tutorials and tutorial items OR does it instead make sense to have the endpoint `/site/:id` that would pull Site's tutorials and tutorial items all in one go like so in `app/controllers/sites_controller.rb`:

```
# GET /sites/:id
  def show
    # get @Site.tutorial.tutorial_items
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Either way is obviously possible. One option is to do have the `/site/:id` endpoint accept a parameter, something like `/sites/1?tutorials=true`. This works well for simple APIs but can quickly get out of had for larger APIs with more diverse clients and many potential options.

If you are likely to be doing something more complex you might want to start out using an API style more like Facebook's FQL or Netflix's Falcor API style. There are a few Gems which can help you with either one.